# Let $F = \{A\subseteq \mathbb{R}: A\subseteq [0,1] \text{ or } A^c\subseteq [0,1]\}$, is F a ring?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, ring-theory, metric-spaces

Let $S = \mathbb{R}$ and $F = \{A\subseteq \mathbb{R}: A\subseteq [0,1] \text{ or } A^c\subseteq [0,1]\}$.

**Exercise:** Is $F$ a ring?

I know that $F$ is a ring if

i) $\emptyset \in F.$

ii) $A,B \in F \Rightarrow B\backslash A \in F.$

iii) $n\in \mathbb{N}, \, A_1, A_2, ..., A_n \in F \Rightarrow \, \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^{n} A_j \in F$.

*My approach:*

i) Is clearly satisfied.

ii) Pick two random subsets $A,B \in F$. We have that $A\subseteq [0,1]$ or $A^c\subseteq [0,1]$ and $B\subseteq [0,1]$ or $B^c\subset [0,1]$. Consider four different cases:

When $A,B\subseteq [0,1]$ we have that $B\backslash A = \emptyset$ or $B\backslash A = [0,a)\cup (b,1]$ with $a< b,a,b\in(0,1)$ or $B\backslash A = [a,b]$ with $a,b\in[0,1]$. In this case for every $x\in(B\backslash A)$ we have that $x\in F$

When $A \subseteq [0,1]$ and $B^c \subseteq [0,1]$ we have that $B\backslash A = B$. $B\in F \Rightarrow B\backslash A \in F$.

When $A^c \subseteq [0,1]$ and $B\subseteq [0,1]$ we have that $B\backslash A = B$. $B \in F \Rightarrow B\backslash A\in F$.

When $A^c, B^c\subseteq [0,1]$ we have that $B\backslash A = \emptyset$ or $B\backslash A \subseteq (a, b) \cup (c, d)$ with $a<b<c<d, a,b,c,d \in (-\infty, \infty)$ or $B\backslash A \subseteq [a,b]$ with $a<b, a,b \in (-\infty, \infty)$. In this case for every $x\in B\backslash A$ we have that $x\in F$.

iii) Pick any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n \in F$. For every $1\leq i\leq n$ we have that if $x\in A_i$, then $x\in F$. Obviously for any $x\in \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n A_i$ we have that $x\in F$.

**Question:** is my solution correct/how would I solve this exercise correctly if not? Sometimes I feel my approach is a bit too intuitive (especially in part iii).

Comment: You probably messed up your notation and confused $\mathbb R$ with $F$ and in the definition of $F$ it porbably should be $A \subset \mathbb R: \dots$

Comment: @klirk thanks edited!

Comment: What is meant by $\mathbb R$ here? Don't you mean something like $\wp(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Also, $S$ doesnt appear anywhere in your question besides the first line

Comment: Wake up.  There is no A  **in** R that is  a subset of R.  Thus F is empty.

Comment: @klirk This is the way the question is formulated in my textbook!

Comment: titusAdam: there is a typo in the textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerns ii)

$$A\subseteq[0,1]\text{ or }A^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]\iff A^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]\text{ or }A\subseteq[0,1]$$ or equivalently

$$A\in F\iff A^{\complement}\in F$$

So $F$ is closed under complements.

After this observation proving that $A,B\in F\implies A\cup B\in F$ is enough.

This because:$$B\setminus A=\left(B^{\complement}\cup A\right)^{\complement}$$

---

Concerns iii)

we discern the following cases:

If $A,B\subseteq[0,1]$ then $A\cup B\subseteq[0,1]$

If $A^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]$ then $\left(A\cup B\right)^{\complement}\subseteq A^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]$

If $B^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]$ then $\left(A\cup B\right)^{\complement}\subseteq B^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]$ (essentially the same as the former case)

---

**edit** to clarify

Observe that: $$A=\left(A^{\complement} \right)^{\complement}\tag1$$

So in this context for $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ the following statements are evidently equivalent:

- $A\in F$
- $A\subseteq[0,1]\text{ or }A^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]$ (on base of definition of $F$)
- $A^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]\text{ or }A\subseteq[0,1]$ (essentially the same as former statement)
- $A^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]\text{ or }\left(A^{\complement} \right)^{\complement}\subseteq[0,1]$ (on base of $(1)$)
- $A^{\complement}\in F$ (on base of definition of $F$)

Comment: Their union is $\mathbb R$ whose complement is $\emptyset \subset [0,1]$

Comment: @klirk You are correct. I adapted my answer.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for your reply, I don't understand your answers though. Concerning ii) you say that $A\subseteq [0,1]$ or $A^c \subseteq [0,1] \Leftrightarrow A^c \subseteq [0,1]$ or $A \subseteq [0,1]$; isn't this always true? I'm obviously mistaken, but it seems to me that your saying statement $A \Leftrightarrow$ statement $A$. And why is this equivalent to $A\in F \Leftrightarrow A^c \in F$?

Comment: Are things clear now? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for iii) is not complete.

You only showed that if $A,B \subset [0,1]$, then $A\cup B \subset [0,1]$.
Similarly it is easy to show that if $A, B \subset [0,1]^C$, then $A\cup B \subset [0,1]^C$.

Now assume $A, B \in F$ with $A \subset [0,1]$ and $B^C \subset [0,1]$.
Then $(A\cup B)^C = A^C \cap B^C \subset B^C \subset [0,1]$, so $A \cup B \in F$.

---

Regarding ii):

Your proof seems right, but a bit cumbersome.
I would prefer to use that $A\setminus B = A \cap B^C\subset A, B^C$.

So if $A$ or $B^C$ are subsets of $[0,1]$, then so is $A\setminus B$.
The missing case is that $A^C$ and $B$ are subsets of $[0,1]$. Then look at the complement $(A \setminus B)^C = A^C \cup B \subset [0,1]. $